# Adding new column to dataframe with value based on existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would I go through a dataframe and add a new column containing values based on whether the existing columns have the same values for each row?

For example in the following Dataframe I want to add a new column that contains 1 in the rows where Col1 and Col2 contain 1s and 0 if they do not all contain 1.

```
Col1 Col2
1    1
1    1
1    0 
0    0 
0    1
1    1
1    1
```

The output that I would want is

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    1
1    1    1
1    0    0 
0    0    0 
0    1    0
1    1    1
1    1    1
```

Ideally this would be scalable for more columns in the future (new column would only contain 1 if all columns contain 1)

Answer (score 1):

If need check if all columns are `1` use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with casting to integers, working if data are only `1` and `0`:

```
df['col3'] = df.all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If need test only `1`, working for any data use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for `==`:

```
df['col3'] = df.eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If want select columns for check add subset:

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2']

df['col3'] = df[cols].all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['col3'] = df[cols].eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

if there are only 0 and 1 you try with [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html)

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col1'].mul(df['Col2'])
```

Comment: check now:) @ jezrael

Comment: Super, now working very nice for 2 columns fileld by `1` or `0`

Comment: @ansev Creative solution! +1